# Unidirectional OneToMany with Composite Primary key not persisted

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have an ER relationship from a legacy DB (MS SQL Server based as below

[image]

The way that I'm currently trying to convert this to the JPA 2.1 style is as below

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Orders implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "OrderHistory",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "OrderNumber", referencedColumnName = "OrderNumber", nullable = false)
            }
    )
    private List<OrderHistory> orderHistory;

    ----Other properties, Getters and Setters

}


@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "OrderNumber")
public class SpecialOrders extends Orders implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "OrderNumber", referencedColumnName = "OrderNumber", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @OrderBy("sequenceNumber ASC")
    private List<Items> items;

    ----Other properties, Getters and Setters
}


@Entity
@IdClass(ItemsPK.class)
public class Items implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SequenceNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer sequenceNumber;


    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "CustomOptions",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "OrderNumber", referencedColumnName = "OrderNumber", nullable = false),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "SequenceNumber", referencedColumnName = "SequenceNumber", nullable = false)
            }
    )
    private List<CustomOptions> customOptions;  

    ----Other properties, Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class ItemsPK implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SequenceNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer sequenceNumber;
        ----Getters and Setters
}


@Entity
@IdClass(CustomOptionsPK.class)
public class CustomOptions implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SequenceNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer sequenceNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OptionNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer optionNumber;   

    ----Other properties, Getters and Setters
}

public class CustomOptionsPK implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SequenceNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer sequenceNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "OptionNumber", nullable = false)
    private Integer optionNumber;   

    ----Getters and Setters
}
```

With the above code, I see that hibernate does below

1. INSERTs into Orders and gets the GeneratedId for OrderNumber
2. INSERTs into SpecialOrders, using the orderNumber retrieved above.
3. Attemps to INSERT into Items table, with a NULL value in the orderNumber and then fails because the orderNumber is a NOT NULL column.

Subsequently, If add a "Simple" primary key to Items table and make the orderNumber as a NULLable column, then the below happens:

1. INSERTs into Orders and gets the GeneratedId for OrderNumber
2. INSERTs into SpecialOrders, using the orderNumber retrieved above.
3. INSERTs into Items table with orderNumber as NULL value and gets the generated id of the Items table row.
4. Updates the row of Items table with the orderNumber from parent, using the retrieved id for Items.
5. Attemps to INSERT into CustomOptions table, with a NULL value in the orderNumber and then fails because the orderNumber is a NOT NULL column.

As per the above sequence, it seems that:

- Composite Primary key doesnt seem to be working correctly or not supported.
- Hibernate is handling the OneToMany relationship inefficiently by issuing an INSERT followed by an UPDATE, instead of just an insert.

Any idea if my understanding is correct? The only way of fixing this issue seems to be that I need to remove the composite primary key and replace it with a simple one.